# Tkinter + MultiProcessing: Tkinter Keeps Opening Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

I have written this code to basically opens a GUI made in Tkinter and also runs the scheduler both together every thing is working fine as long as i am running this code on PyCharm...

Now if I convert the code to exe using "PyInstaller", After i run the code the GUI keeps opening again and again until I terminate the task..

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import tkinter as tk

# IMPORTING SCHEDULER AND ADDREDDITACCOUNT GUI

from app.scheduler import schedule_upload
from app.addRedditAccount import AddRedditAccount


if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = tk.Tk()
    AddRedditAccount(window)

    schedule = Process(name='schedule', target=schedule_upload)
    schedule.start()

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you run .exe in console to see error messages? maybe it shows something interesting.

Comment: do you really have to run Process? Maybe you could do it with `window.after(milliseconds, function)` to execute function periodically.

Comment: Without knowing what those imported files do it's impossible for us to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are trying to use `multiprocessing` in an executable.  I am assuming you are using a Windows OS as well. All you need to do is add a call to `freeze_support` from the `multiprocessing` module.

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support  # <-- added this
import tkinter as tk

# IMPORTING SCHEDULER AND ADDREDDITACCOUNT GUI

from app.scheduler import schedule_upload
from app.addRedditAccount import AddRedditAccount
freeze_support()   # <--- added this


if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = tk.Tk()
    AddRedditAccount(window)

    schedule = Process(name='schedule', target=schedule_upload)
    schedule.start()

    window.mainloop()
```

Recompile and your executable should work fine.

You can learn more about `freeze_support` in the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=freeze_support#multiprocessing.freeze_support)